# How to find every combination of numbers that fulfill the requirements

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, permutation

I have this dataset:

```
input <- tribble(~id, ~soil_depth_min, ~soil_depth_max, ~c,
                 1, 0, 15, 10,
                 1, 0, 7.5, 8,
                 1, 7.5, 15, 3,
                 1, 15, 30, 11,
                 2, 0, 15, 25,
                 2, 15, 30, 7,
                 3, 0, 20, 16)
```

And I want to calculate the sum of the `c` column for each group of measurements that go up to 30.

What I want is for each group (grouped by `id`) to have sub-groups containing every possible combination of soil depth measurements that add up to at most 30.
For group 2 this is easy

```
  25  +   7 is the only combination
(0-15) (15-30)
```

and same for group 3. But group 1 is more difficult, because there are two ways to split up the measurements to reach 30.

```
  10  +   11
(0-15) (15-30)
and
  8    +    3   +  11
(0-7.5) (7.5-15) (15-30)
```

Are the two possible combinations for group 1.
Here is my expected output:

```
output <- tribble(~id, ~lowest_depth, ~lowest_depth_c,
                  1, 30, 21,
                  1, 30, 22,
                  2, 30, 32,
                  3, 20, 16)
```

The way it should work is like this:
In group 1, we have 4 measurements of c: 0 to 15, 0 to 7.5, 7.5 to 15, and 15 to 30.
This means there are actually two ways for group 1 to measured 0 to 30: we can either sum the values for 0-7.5, 7.5-15, and 15-30, or we can just sum the values for 0-15 and 15-30.
I want both combinations included in my final table.

I tried to solve it like this:

```
input %>%
    mutate(soil_depth = paste0(soil_depth_min,"-",soil_depth_max)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarise(lowest_depth = -sum(-soil_depth_max[soil_depth_max<=30], soil_depth_min[soil_depth_max<=30]),
              lowest_depth_c = sum(c[soil_depth_max<=30]))
```

which outputs

```
     id lowest_depth lowest_depth_c
  <dbl>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1     1           45             32
2     2           30             32
3     3           20             16
```

This didn't work because it summed the four measurements of group 1 together, whereas I want it to first break that group into two separate calculations of 8 + 3 + 11 = 22 and 10 + 11 = 21

Comment: This sounds like a version of the "knapsack" problem. The `adagio` package has some tools for those.

Comment: How big is your real data, in terms of id and in terms of typical observations per id? The smaller it is, the simpler an approach may suffice.

Comment: In your example data, the sample combinations fit perfectly and there is no overlap of any ranges between two measurements. Is overlap ok, or would that exclude it? For instance, what would happen if row 2's max depth were 8 or 14.5 instead of 7.5?

Comment: There's never any overlap of the ranges within the group